# Как получить любой элемент у объекта

Tags: c#, объекты

Есть объект `obj` у него есть поля `name` и `age` (программа не знает название и количество полей) мне надо взять все его поля и напечатать.

Answer (score 1):

Это можно сделать с помощью [рефлексии](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/14.1.php):

```cs
public class Test {
    public string name;
    public int age;
}
```

```cs
Test obj = new Test { name = "Вася", age = 10 };

foreach (var field in typeof(Test).GetFields()) { // Получаем информацию о полях 
    Console.WriteLine($"{field.Name}: {field.GetValue(obj)}"); // Выводим имя и значение поля
}
```

Вывод:

```
name: Вася
age: 10
```

Comment: по умолчанию только публичные поля выбираются